# Java Filter string values separated by comma

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Below is the string of values separated by commas. Need to filter each values and append them with specific values.

String values - `Hello, MyName, Is, XYZ`

Above is the string that i am sending through an API

What i want is - How to add `(_true)` this string value to each element on above **String Values**. That also to few String values that i am checking with some specific condition

So that it should be like below in that API call which is sent to FrontEnd.

`Hello(_true), MyName, Is, XYZ(_true)`

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: > How to add (_true) this string value to each element on above String Values
But your example contradicts that ?

Comment: What is the logic behind why only `Hello` and `XYZ` get a value appended to them?

Comment: Do you want this in Java or in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String StringAppenderWithLogic(String given, String del) {
    return String.join(del, Arrays.stream(given.split(del)).
            map(p -> {
                //put any logic specific to your requirement
                if (p.trim().startsWith("H") || p.trim().startsWith("X")) {
                    p = p + "(_true)";

                }
                return p;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: Very Thanks your solution worked for me as i wanted. Best Answer

Comment: Thanks, Ravi , Gald that solved your query, if possible can you please upvote  my answer as well

Comment: Sure @anurag saxena - i am new i need minimum 15 reputation for that. That will be possible, if you upvote my question and comments. I may get minimum 15 reputation. then i will be eligible to upvote answer. But still i was eligible to accept it as answer

Comment: Done from my side 

Comment: Done from my side as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String apiOutput = "Hello, MyName, Is, XYZ";
        
        List<String> s = List.of(apiOutput.split(", ")).stream()
            .map(Main::stringController)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        String result = String.join(", ", s);
        
        System.out.println(result);
        
    }
    
    private static String stringController(String in){
        if(hasMatchCondition(in)){
            return in + "(_true)";
        }
        return in;
    }
    
    private static boolean hasMatchedCondition(String in){
        //place your logic here
        
        //[START] exemple
        if(in.length() == 5 || in.length() == 3)
            return true;
        return false;
        //[END] exemple
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).